# model = model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2),input_shape=(48,48,1))) AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'add'

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, machine-learning, conv-neural-network

This error occur in Maxpooling stage while i train my CNN model
Error: Attribute Error: 'None Type' object has no attribute 'current'. Please help.

```
 model = model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2),input_shape=(48,48,1)))
```

Comment: need to see code for how input is generated

Answer (score 0):

The question is missing some info, but I think I can see what's going on.

Assuming that model was at some point a tf.models.Sequential() I guess you did something like:

```
model = models.Sequential()
model = model.add(...)
model = model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2),input_shape=(48,48,1)))
```

However, that's not quite how model.add(..) works. Instead of returning a new model, it modifies the existing model.
Instead you should do something like:

```
model = models.Sequential() # create a first model
model.add(...) # add things to the existing model
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2),input_shape=(48,48,1)))
```